# Expand variable in the JSON payload of a curl command

Tags: shell-script, curl, json

I have a shell script that sends a post request with curl.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS='["sleep", "200s"]'

STATUS="successful"

if [ "$STATUS" = "successful" ]
then

    NEXT_JOB_ID=$(curl -s "localhost:5050/processes/gdalEcho/execution" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
        "commandOverride": ["sleep", "200s"]
    }')
    echo "$NEXT_JOB_ID"
fi
```

It runs fine until I try to replace `["sleep", "200s"]` with the `NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS` variable. How can I expand a variable inside JSON payload of curl?

```bash
NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS='["sleep", "200s"]'

STATUS="successful"

if [ "$STATUS" = "successful" ]
then

    NEXT_JOB_ID=$(curl -s "localhost:5050/processes/gdalEcho/execution" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
        "commandOverride": ' "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" '
    }')
    echo "$NEXT_JOB_ID"
fi
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes when using variables, change `--data` to double quotes and escape double quotes in the JSON you send, like this:  `--data` parameter: `"{ \"commandOverride\": \"$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS\" }"`

Comment: I think you might change `--header 'Content-Type: application/json'` to  `--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and `--data ..yourtext..` to: `--data-urlencode "commandOverride=$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS"`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon the first one does not work. Will let you know the result of second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is actually a couple of space characters on these lines in your code:

```
--data '{
    "commandOverride": ' "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" '
}')
```

The 2nd single quote breaks out of the single-quoted string, which is the option argument to the `--data` option of `curl`. The space character just after the single quote ensures that the string in `$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS` will be *its own argument* to `curl`, and you then add `}` (preceded by a newline) as an additional extra argument, probably confusing `curl` even more.

You *could* solve this by changing the middle line to

```
"commandOverride": '"$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS"'
```

... but you could also use `jq` to insert your `$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS` value into the form body (which would ensure that the resulting JSON body is well formed and valid).

---

If you want to pass a well-formed JSON document (your array) as a top-level key in a JSON document used with `--data` in your `curl` invocation, you may do as follows:

```bash
NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS='["sleep", "200s"]'

NEXT_JOB_ID=$(
    formdata=$( jq -c -n --argjson commandOverride "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" '$ARGS.named' ) &&
    curl -s \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data "$formdata" \
        'http://localhost:5050/processes/gdalEcho/execution'
)

printf '%s\n' "$NEXT_JOB_ID"
```

Here, the shell variable `formdata` (which is local to the command substitution) will get the value

```json
{"commandOverride":["sleep","200s"]}
```

This is created using `jq`, which will insert the given JSON fragment as the value for a `commandOverride` key.

A variant of the above allows you to avoid writing JSON entirely and instead stores your array as an array in the shell:

```bash
NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS=( 'sleep' '200s' )

NEXT_JOB_ID=$(
    formdata=$(
        jq -c -n '{ commandOverride: $ARGS.positional }' --args "${NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS[@]}"
    ) &&
    curl -s \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data "$formdata" \
        'http://localhost:5050/processes/gdalEcho/execution'
)

printf '%s\n' "$NEXT_JOB_ID"
```

The above assumes a shell that has named arrays.  For the `/bin/sh` shell, use `set -- sleep 200s` to set the list of positional parameters to the array elements, and then `"$@"` to insert that list after `--args` in the arguments to `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter json in bash, I default to using jq, so using your script as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS='["sleep", "200s"]'

STATUS="successful"

if [ "$STATUS" = "successful" ]
then
    echo curl -s "localhost:5050/processes/gdalEcho/execution" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "$(echo "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" | jq -rc '{"commandOverride":.}')"
    echo "$NEXT_JOB_ID"
fi
```

I couldn't test this against an actual curl call, so I am just echoing out the resulting command. I believe this should at least get you half way.

Comment: You don't need to pipe to `jq`: `jq --argjson cmd "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" -nrc '{commandOverride: $cmd}'`, or if you have `jq` 1.6: `jq --argjson commandOverride "$NEXT_JOB_COMMANDS" -nrc '$ARGS.named'`